# Issues Installing & Booting from USB HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

So I've installed Ubuntu in the past, on internal and external drives. However, I can't seem to figure it out currently. The issue is that in UEFI it won't detect the external HDD I want to boot from in my BIOS. It does in Legacy but in Legacy, whether I pick my external or internal drive it asks me to select a bootup disk. The process I took:

1. Download Ubuntu 17-10-64-bit
2. Using Rufus I turn a 16Gb USB thumb stick into my installation media. It asks me to write in ISO or DD mode, not sure which to choose so I just choose the default aka ISO.
3. Booted in UEFI to the USB stick.
4. Hit install Ubuntu, went through all the steps to install on my external 500GB WD drive. I'm installing it alongside windows but on a separate drive.
5. Here's where I think another issue may lay, it says it needs to restart to finish the installation, so I hit restart and get the text down the screen but it just stops and doesn't continue. So I force shut it down and attempt to boot from the external drive, but it doesn't show in UEFI and won't boot in Legacy as said previously. It also doesn't have any options before windows boots to boot into Ubuntu.
   So that's where I am now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See Bug # 1173457 , installer uses first EFI partition it sees, not the one on the device (or a specific one) you specify.  Copy the entire internal disk's EFI to the USB disk's EFI, and try booting it.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the summary report ( not full report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred Wasn't able to get a live boot so here is my system info: https://pastebin.com/uS94F1Pp

Comment: @ubfan1 Not entirely sure how to do that, I'm assuming you mean take the EFI from my windows install and transfer it to the EFI on the disk I have installed to and then attempt to boot. If that's the case I'm not sure where to find the EFI for windows, did a bit of research and it's apparently hidden in some drive?

Comment: The EFI partitions have a FAT filesystem, so the bootloaders are just files.  The Microsoft bootloaders are in /EFI/Microsoft  and the Ubuntu bootloader(s) are in /EFI/ubuntu.  A default bootloader is put into /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, which is a copy of one of the other bootloaders.  Mount the two EFIs and just copy everything, keeping the directory structure.

Comment: Not sure how that applies, I've been able to install it on an external HDD. So I have two EFI partitions. One in my internal SSD which boots windows, and one in my external HHD which should in theory boot Kali Linux. My issue is that in UEFI mode my bios isn't recognizing my external HHD for me to boot. It for some reason recognizes it in legacy mode but then just asks me to insert bootable media, won't boot into windows either with legacy mode. @ubfan1

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue, there was nothing wrong with the installation or anything. What happened was that in my BIOS it didn't recognize my external HDD with the Ubuntu installation on it as a different drive than my internal SSD with Windows. I have the boot order for disks and such, but there was another boot order option within my bios. Which allowed me to select the EFI I wanted to boot from. After I selected the ubuntu installation what used to show the internal SSD windows drive then switched to grub allowing me to select between ubuntu or windows bootup.